# Modified Date in Explorer view not updated when the file is edited

Tags: document-library, date-time, explorer-view

I modified some Word documents more than a month after they were put into SharePoint. SharePoint shows the updated dates, but the explorer view still has the original file date/time, and the content of those files was definitely changed. When I right-click the files and select properties, that also does **NOT** show the modified date/time.

Any thoughts on why it doesn't update the modified date of the file, and how can I change that behavior?

Comment: @Robert Lindren, why do you insist on removing my "Thanks" at the end of my question?  Is there a rule against politeness on this site?

Comment: You can surely keep it, but on SharePoint stackexchange we usually edit it out all "fluff". The purpose is to let the question and context be in focus :) If I had not edited it out, surely someone else would have I'm afraid.